# Where are my LocalDB files?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Using the Entity Framework code first, I managed to write to an mdf file, and I could find them stored in my user folder, but what is bugging me, is when I delete the file and run the app again it doesn't create the file second time, but as if it knows that it was created and gives the following error.

> An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "DB" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'PC\user'.
>
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

The DB files were created successfully in the first time I specified the name in the connection string

```
private MyDBContext() : base(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True")
```

So my guess is that LocalDB is storing what mdf database files were created, and it will attempt to connect to it if it was previously created and not to attempt searching for it in the location.

**So my question is:**

Where is this type of register of LocalDB?
I would like to delete these "references"

Comment: `LocalDB` is a developer-optimized version of SQL Server Express - **not** MS Access - so therefore it creates `.mdf` (and `.ldf`) database files - not `.mdb` ....

Comment: Sorry my mistake, yes you are right, I meant mdf files. Corrected it

Comment: which is the provider you are using? as far as I know SQL Server Express provider can't target db images in .mdf files. Maybe your localdb instance is still there (you can use ssms for example to look at your localdb instances), but can't connect to it and therefore can't write its contents to the .mdf file again.

Comment: I am not using SQL Server. I am using LocaLDB as you can see from the connection string. The instance is there, but it seems it know that the file with this name was created, so deleting it physically won't help, how can I delete it from the instance?